# How to do vectorized summations in an exponent and apply it to a whole data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a summation function to each row of a data.frame.  My function is as follows:

```
fun <- function(a, b, t) sum((a+b)^(0:t))
```

I am using the following data.frame to test the code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3,
                 y = 1:3)
```

And I want it to work something like this:

```
fun(df$x, df$y, 0, 3)
```

Essentially, I want my function to go through `df` and find the sum from `t=0 to t=3` of `(df$x + df$y)^t`.  The function works fine for a single input, but due to the nature of the `sum()` function, this does not work on data.frames.  I know I could do this with a loop, but I would like to keep the vectorized version of the summation (that is, I like using the `:` operator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
fun2 <- function(a, b, t1, t2) rowSums(outer(a+b, t1:t2, `^`))
```

Comparing results:

```
> fun2(df$x, df$y, 0, 3)
[1]  15  85 259

> fun(df$x[1], df$y[1], 3)
[1] 15
> fun(df$x[2], df$y[2], 3)
[1] 85
> fun(df$x[3], df$y[3], 3)
[1] 259
```

Also note that your function declaration needs two inputs, `t1` and `t2`.